# Wronskian is not defined

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

Suppose a general question: What does it mean that the Wronskian at a certain point is not even defined? take for example two solutions for a second order ODE: $$ y_1(x)=\frac{1}{x^{3}} ~~~~\text{and} ~~~~y_2(x)=x^{2}~.$$

We get that $W=\frac{5}{x^{2}}$ which is not defined on $x=0$.

What is the correct explanation?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is your doubt, but I think a good explanation is that thopse solutions to the ODE are *not* defined in a domain containing zero...which seems pretty obvious.

Comment: $y_1$ is also not defined at $x=0$, so this is not surprising. The Wronskian of linearly independent solutions of a second order linear ODE $y'' + a(x) y' + b(x)=0$ is a constant multiple of $\exp(-A(x))$ where $A$ is an antiderivative of $a$.  In this case $A(x) = 2 \ln(x) + c$, so $a(x) = 2/x$.  Again, this is not defined at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your differential equation is by definition a differentiable function defined on an interval of existence.

In your example the function $y_1(x)=\frac{1}{x^3}$ is not defined at $x=0$ so at this point the wronskian is not defined.

We need to stay within the interval of existence.